# How to download from double hop SFTP?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, sftp, winscp

I am new to linux and am having trouble doing this.

I need to download files and this is currently what I do to access the file.

SSH into server A.

From server A, SSH to server B

After logging into server B, run the following command:

```
sudo -i -u testuser
```

I enter a password and then I have the privileges I need.

How would I replicate this with WinSCP?  I can login to the server following the guide here:
https://superuser.com/questions/303486/sftp-over-double-server-hop

But I cannot download the files because I don't have permissions.  How do I execute that sudo command and enter a password in the login process using WinSCP?  Or an alternative program (that runs on OSX).  My ultimate goal is to download a file form the(double remote) computer to my local computer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine two "advanced" features of WinSCP.

**Tunneling**: That's what the Super User question you have referred to deals with:
[SFTP over double server hop](https://superuser.com/q/303486/213663)

**Sudo**: There's another Super User question that deals with this:
[How to change user in WinSCP?](https://superuser.com/q/647919/213663)
It is basically covered in WinSCP FAQ [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)
This is a tricky part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution you've already found, just use:

`ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh myfirsthop nc -w 10 %h %p' testuser@mydestination`

Comment: Where in WinSCP where would I put this line?